# Putting a process list into a combo box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

All I want, is that when I click on the comboBox1 box, that it will display all of the processes currently running.

```
private void comboBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     comboBox1.Items.Clear();
     Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
     for (int i = 0; i < MyProcess.Length; i++)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(MyProcess[i].ProcessName + "-" + MyProcess[i].Id);
}
```

Why does it refuse to work? :s

Comment: I've tried and it works. But as it was said, listbox would be more apropriate for this task

Comment: Tried it to, and it also works for me

Comment: Your code works, what specific problem are you having.... refuse to work is a little vague

Comment: Have you tried loading your combobox on form load, instead of using mouseclick

Comment: And also be more specific in what is not working, cause for us your code works.

Comment: When I click on the combobox, nothing appears, it stays empty as if nothing was picked up. Sorry, first post here was a pretty bad post I know :P. Why does it show the process's for everyone else, but it won't for me? It just has the little white part like as if nothing shows up

Comment: in debug mode look what what precesses are returned by Process.GetProcesses() method. May be there is a problem?

Comment: @AaronHoush if you want to list the processes you need to do it under form1_load() and not under comboBox1_MouseClick()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the code in the constructor right after the initializeComponets my guess is that you reset the combo box on each click as you reload the data then (including the click to select a value) and also your current code would not update the values if you use tab to focus the combobox!

Answer (score 2):

Better use a ListBox, so you can show all process on their own line, instead of having to drop it down like you are doing now in your combobox/dropdown

for more info look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx

Change your code like this to do a test

add this method

```
private void LoadProcesses()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < MyProcess.Length; i++)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", MyProcess[i].ProcessName, MyProcess[i].Id));

}
```

and in your form loaded event add:

```
LoadProcesses();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the problem is, but this code works fine:

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Process.GetProcesses().Select<Process, string>(F => F.ProcessName + "- " + F.Id).ToArray());
```

Actually, maybe the number of process changes, and that can invalidate the indexer....